# JavaScript Document.Head is Null

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, onload

Getting an error when running the following code in IE 8, but not in other browsers:

'document.head' is null or not an object

Here is my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>

    <script>
   function load() {
    document.getElementsByID("myFrame");
    }
   </script>
   </head> 
   <body>       

    <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/bTlK6CRNcL/embed/" width="300" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="myFrame" onload="load()"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Framework I'm using for compatibility across browsers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`document.head` fails because IE8 doesn't support it (no version of IE before 9); it's a new feature of HTML5. Instead, you could use the following in any browser:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

If `document.head` is defined (available), it will short-circuit and use that immediately. If it's not defined, it will use the `document.getElementsByTagName` part, which will find it in any browser.

Unless you want to have this kind of `this || that` throughout your code, it's safe and good enough to just always use `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`.

---

**References:**

- `document.head` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head (scroll to the bottom for browser support)
- `document.getElementsByTagName` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: @asg: Presumably, the Instagram embed contains `document.head`, and you can't edit that.

Comment: Probably no easy fix, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: What about document.documentElement ?

Comment: @Richards What about it? That refers to the `<html>` element, but we're talking about the `<head>` element

Comment: @lan jeesssh, failed on this one.. Long day. You saved me! Thanks!